# pclose issue in powerPC

Tags: c, arm, embedded, powerpc

i was creating an application for an embedded system, which uses popen to run /usr/bin/find, however i came across a weird issue,
my code was something like...

```
int main() {
  char str[2048]
  fun1(str, 2048);
  return 0;
}

int fun1(char* str, int cap) {
   return fun2(str,<command>, cap);
}

int fun2(char* str, char* cmd, int cap) {
  FILE* fptr = popen(cmd, "r");
  char line_buffer[2048];
  int total = 0;
  int count = 0;
  str[0] = '\0';

  while (count = (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), fptr)) != 0) {
    total += count;
    strcat(str, line_buffer);
  }

  pclose(fptr);
  return total;

}
```

when pclose is called, my application goes back to main as if main() was called again, this only happens on PowerPC but not on ARM devices, why is this?

Comment: fun2() is ignoring the cap argument. I the total amount of characters red from the line exceeds 2014, a buffer overflow will happen. Also: the total counter counts the number of successfull calls to fgets, not the number of lines or characters.

Comment: A certain indicator of undefined behavior bugs in your program is that it breaks on some platforms but seems to work on other platforms (latent bug).

Comment: strcat() is a horribly inefficient way of doing that - it has to find the end of the string on every iteration, when you already know where the end of the string is.  Use the value `total` to index the buffer and `strcpy()` instead, then increment total _after_ the `strcpy()`, not forgetting to test `total+count < cap` before.

Comment: Or don't even copy - do your read directly into the offset location in the destination buffer, with an allowed size given by the space remaining in the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my application goes back to main as if main() was called again

If I had to take a gamble, I would say that your code crashes and what you see is actually an automatic soft-reset.

But why does the program crash?

I would deem that this happens because you call `strcat()` without any bound checking. Each line you read can be as long as 2048 bytes, whereas the entire concatenated string is also only 2048 bytes long.

It might just happen that your buffer is defined too close to `FILE *fptr`, thus it overrides it and `pclose()` tries to close an invalid handler and crashes.

To **verify** that this is the problem try changing `char str[2048]` to `char str[65536]` and see if it reproduces.

To **fix** the issue, use the safer `strncat` instead of `strcat` to avoid memory corruptions.